# Dynamically display hashes/data/JSON in the view

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to dynamically insert headers and tbody into the HTML using Ruby and Sinatra. Until the moment i've got the headers but i'm not having success on the body.

Here's my code:

```
get '/list' do
 urlData = "http://localhost:3000/data"
 responseData = RestClient.get urlData

 @banks = JSON.parse(responseData.body)
 @keys = @banks[0].keys # OK
 @values =  @banks.map(&:values) # Trying to put in the html

 erb :list

end
```

The view, as follows:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <% @keys.each do |key| %>
   <th><%= key %></th>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <% @values.each do |value| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= value %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The JSON format:

```
[
 {
  "ID": 247,
  "Code": "246",
  "Name": "ABC BANK S.A."
 },
 {
  "ID": 248,
  "Code": "25",
  "Name": "Beta Bank"
 }, ...
]
```

How is displaying:
[image]
A way to solve is placing kind of a increment, like

```
<%= value[0] %>
```

but i can't find an elegant way.

Comment: ... and what is the response (in your browser)?

Comment: Only the headers are working fine.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything to the body. You iterate over `@keys` but not `@values` which I assume you want in the `tbody`. Can you post that code?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot i've updated the problem description

Comment: @peter working but just appeared the first row of the json

Comment: @peter Yes, i think the tbody is correct. When i run a "p @values" is showing what's in the view. I'm trying to guess how can I call all the values.

Comment: was ont the wrong path, thought you didn't get all your values but it's about how to present them, see my answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the values in separate td tags, you can do that like this. The @values is an array of arrays (the rows) which contain the cell values.

```
<tbody>
 <% @values.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <% row.each do |value| %>
     <td><%= value %></td>
    <%end%>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

EDIT: you get your array of arrays like this

```
banks.map{|x| x.values}
#[[247, "246", "ABC BANK S.A."], [248, "25", "Beta Bank"]]
```

and you pass it to your view like this, not sure if necessary

```
erb :list, :locals => {values: @values, keys: @keys}
```

Comment: I'm understanding now, but on the controller how can i pass all the values? Using  (at)values =  (at)banks.values gives me an error of 'undefined methods 'values''.

Comment: The question is: what can i pass to the controller for the view works correctly with this <tbody> you've posted?

Comment: Peter, thanks for your help. Finally i've got the 'array of arrays' thing, i was trying to understand it!

Comment: Sure! Accepted!